# Code Pointers in VS.Net 2003 are out of whack

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, visual-studio, debugging

I have a .net 1.1 project in VS.Net 2003 (using C#) in which I can set a breakpoint in one method, and step through code just fine, but when I hit one specific method (which we also wrote), the breakpoints and code pointers go "whacky", for lack of a better term.  If the breakpoint is on line 100, the execution pointer stops on line 101.  The syntax highlighting that colors the breakpoint red will still be on 100, but it will only be as long as line 101 is (which is to say, shorter than line 100).  As you F10 through the code, the deviance between where the code is really executing and where the execution pointer is placed appears to get bigger.  Has anyone ever encountered this type of problem before, and if so, what might be a solution to resyncing things so I can accurately debug my program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Your debug symbols (.pdb files) are out of synch with the actual code. Close Visual Studio and delete the "bin" and "obj" folders from all of the affected projects. Then reopen Visual Studio and rebuild. This should resolve the problem.

Comment: Aw shucks... in my defense, I solved it the same way myself, but I'll give you credit for the solution because a.) you're right, and b.) you entered it before I answered my own question.  Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

Found it... my PDB files got out of sync with the DLL files... cleaned the /bin/ folder and rebuilt, and the problem goes away.

Thanks me. :)